# Control Theory in MATLAB

Tags: control, control-system, matlab

I'm unsure as to why should one move poles in the rltool of MATLAB.

What does doing so signify?

Comment: Far too broad a question. The broad answer is that the positions of the TF poles (roots of the TF denominator) on the s-plane determine the dynamic characteristics of the system, and the poles can be moved to favourable positions by adjusting controller parameter values.

Comment: I am looking for a broad answer.

Comment: How broad? What have you learned in Control Systems so far? Have you covered poles and zeros and transient response? I didn't down-vote, btw.

Comment: To refine, it's an examination question, and I haven't studied about control in MATLAB. I'm not even sure what answer would be sufficient. My guess would be, does moving poles indicate some sort of region of convergence or say something about the stability of the system?

Comment: See answer - very much an overview.

Answer (score 4):

By way of a simple illustration, say you have a system that is, essentially, an integrator and require to close the loop around it to establish some form of feedback control.

The OLTF is: $$\small G(s)= \frac{1}{s}$$

There's a pole at \$\small s=0\$, and if a step were applied, the response would be a ramp \$ (\frac{1}{s^2})\$.

The CLTF is: $$\small \frac{G(s)}{1+G(s)}= \frac{1}{1+s}$$

Which has a pole at \$\small s=-1\$.

The step response of the closed loop is \$\small (1-e^{-t})\$, so it's exponential with a time constant, \$\small \tau=1\:sec\$. Notice that the pole has moved from \$\small s=0\$ to \$\small s=-1\$ by closing the loop (...and the ramp has become a stable exponential).

Now, let's assume that the response is too slow. What to  do? Well, let's try adding a gain, \$\small K>1\$ to the open loop.

The OLTF is now: $$\small KG(s)=\frac{K}{s}$$

and the CLTF is: $$\small \frac{KG(s)}{1+KG(s)}= \frac{K}{K+s}$$.

The pole has moved to \$\small s=-K\$, further from the origin, and the step response is now faster: $$\small (1-e^{-Kt})=(1-e^{-t/\tau})$$

where \$\small \tau =1/K\$.

We may make the system response as fast (or as slow) as we wish by increasing (or decreasing) \$\small K\$. But, of course, there are always practical limitations - the available power of the amplifier providing the gain, \$\small K\$, for example, will place a lower limit on \$\tau\$.

So we may conclude that moving the pole further away from the origin makes the system faster; moving the pole nearer the origin slows things down.

The root locus is actually found by solving the characteristic equation, which is: $$\small 1+KG(s)=0$$
as \$\small K\$ goes from \$\small 0\rightarrow \infty\$

As a more complicated example, take:

$$\small KG(s)=\frac{K}{s(1+s)}$$

giving the characteristic equation:

$$\small 1+KG(s)=1+\frac{K}{s(1+s)}=0$$

or

$$\small s^2+s+K=0$$

When \$\small K=0\$, the locus starts at: \$\small s(s+1)=0\$, i.e. at: \$\small s=0\$ and \$\small s=-1\$;  **the loci start at the open loop poles**. In this case, there are two open loop poles therefore the locus has two branches.

As \$\small K\$ increases from zero, the roots are given by:

$$\small s=\frac{-1\pm \sqrt{1-4K}}{2}$$

Hence, if \$\small K \le 0.25\$ the roots will be real (and migrate towards each other along the real axis), but for \$\small K>0.25\$ the roots are complex and the loci migrate into the complex regions of the s-plane.

Complex roots means the step response is oscillatory.

The general rules for interpreting the pole positions on the root locus are:

- poles in the left half plane are stable; those in the right half plane are unstable (assume stable system, below)
- further from the origin = faster (either \$\small \tau\$ decreases for 1st order root, or \$\small \omega_n\$ increases for a 2nd order root); nearer the origin = slower
- nearer the origin = more dominant; further from origin = less dominant (relative dominance in the case of multiple roots)
- nearer the real axis = less oscillatory; nearer the imaginary axis = more oscillatory
- on the real axis = decaying exponential; on the imaginary axis steady-state sinusoid (i.e. critically stable)
- at the origin = strictly, unstable as step response goes to infinity

Therefore, if we can express the type of response we want, by specifying poles on the s-plane, then we can determine the value of gain that will give us those pole locations.

As you might expect, there's a lot more to it ... for the rest of the story, read the book!